Why isn't this oven igniting?
My friend's oven recently stopped working, and the pilot light for the burners appears to be out. The stovetop burners still ignite and work.
We've searched the oven for some kind of mark indicating a model number, or serial number, but we're not finding anything. Simply holding a lighter to the place where we expect to see flames doesn't have any effect.
Can anyone help with any advice about how to relight this thing? Please see attached pictures; I'm not 100% sure what I'm looking at, and further pics can be taken if needed.





Usually most labels having the make, model, serial number should be on the back.

It does not appear that this oven has a pilot light. The mechanism at the back of the oven burner does not have the extra gas tube to feed a pilot flame. It does appear to have a two-wire-fed glow ignitor. Holding a lighter under there probably won't get the oven working. It probably needs repair service.

Nameplate might be found in the oven door jamb area.

Pilot lights in ovens haven't been a thing in the US for > 40 years. Unlikely this appliance is that old. If the stovetop burners are electronically ignited (click..click...flame) then the oven is almost certainly some sort of electronic ignition as well.

Thank you all for the comments. I believe my question has been answered. Cheers!

There is no pilot to light. There is a hot surface igniter that needs to be replaced, which is a repair.

That looks like a glow-bar, (hot surface igniter) not a pilot light.

Typically the gas valve won't open unless the glow-bar is drawing specified current. We had one that appeared to glow when you looked at it - but it had cracked, and was not drawing enough current to make the gas valve open. A new one made it light right up again.
The dark gray part inside the black cage should glow red-to-orange or even yellow when the oven is turned on.

If you zoom in on the third pic it looks like it might have a crack.
